# What are some alternative communities/forums that are home to engaged linguists?

Tags: syntax, phonology, morphosyntax

I have made accounts on some forums that seem quite lackluster. Quora can be fun, but it's not really enough. Reddit fails in this regard. I would love to find a forum for discussion that I can look forward to visiting on a daily basis. It can be a community/sub-forum of a larger scientific site.

I'm an undergraduate in Linguistics interested in the cognitive sciences, generally speaking. I'd like to learn and discuss with spirited members of the field.

The LinguistList has a selection of attractive mailing lists but not many of them fit the bill of active and relevant to my interests.

I plan on attending the LSI next Summer at UChicago. My objective is to get as involved and engaged with others in the field as possible, as I am currently located at a small liberal arts school with very few colleagues in linguistics – mostly working in a self-guided study format (tutorials and small, niche classes).

Thanks in advance! Perhaps, as a result of this inquiry, I will have the opportunity of joining some exciting discussions with some of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with building a collection of linguistics blogs you follow and engage in discussions there.

For example, the comment threads on Language Log http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/ are frequently very productive, as well.

While Reddit is a bit free wheeling, it's also not a bad place: http://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/

The linguistics tag on Tumblr https://www.tumblr.com/tagged/linguistics also often has items that generate discussion. Start Tumbling and you may soon find yourself engaged in discussions.

The thing about LinguistList is that it is a collection of mailing lists. Most lists are for specific subfields and you have to find one in which you are interested.  http://linguistlist.org/lists/get-lists.cfm.

Comment: I would add the Faculty of Language blog to this list; comments sections are frequently productive and subject matter is up-to-the-minute. (http://facultyoflanguage.blogspot.co.uk/)

Comment: Also, perhaps not so well-known, but a great blog is Talking Brains, curated by two leading academics on the cog/neuro side of things: http://www.talkingbrains.org/